# Capybara not finding javascript

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am new to Capybara testing and am having a few issues.

I have a scenario I am trying to run, and this is the step implementation:

```
When /^I select the signin link$/ do
  click_link 'Sign in'
end
```

I have tried to access this link with xpath, css, and tried the `within` implementation as well. Capybara cannot seem to find it, and returns a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` exception in all cases.

When I load the webpage without JavaScript, the link is not visible, and I'm wondering if this is why Capybara cannot find it. I found a `trigger` method, but am unsure how it works. Does anyone have a working example of `trigger`, or any other ideas for what I should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the selenium webdriver to run this test?  It sounds like you are trying to run a scenario that requires javascript to see certain elements, without using a driver that supports javascript.

In your `.feature` file all you have to do is add this line before the scenario:

```
@javascript
Scenario:  My Scenario
  When blah blah blah
  ...
```

The @javascript tag tells capybara to use selenium-webdriver to run the test.  It'll fire up firefox and go through the test - allowing all javascript functionality to work.  This slows tests down considerably so only use it when absolutely necessary to test ajax-y and javascript-y behavior.

If that still doesn't work you can use this step:

```
Then show me the page
When I select the signin link
```

Which will open the page up for you in a new browser in that page's current state for your inspecting pleasure.

Comment: Thank you. In my head (for some reason) I assumed Capybara would magically know to open a browser. I have installed firefox, and the selenium-webdriver gem (jruby -S gem install selenium-webdriver) and have altered my env.rb file to include (require 'selenium-webdriver').

Comment: I think Capybara requires it itself.  When installing cucumber I just used the --capybara command and everything for it "just worked," and I see no selenium-webdriver required but I definitely have tests that use it.  Feel free to accept this answer as the correct one if it was satisfactory :)

Comment: @Rebecca you can also add this you your `features/support/env.rb` if all your tests depend on javascript, obviating the need for `@javascript` tags everywhere: `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium`